# How to control pnpm workspace build order

Tags: pnpm, pnpm-workspace

I'm working in a large pnpm monorepo (pnpm v7).

The repository contains :

- multiple apps
- multiple shared dependencies
- tooling (shared compilation setup package)

Every package (app or shared library) may reference any shared library (no circular ref though)

The compilation setup package is gulp helper that setup the compilation tasks for each app and some shared components.

It means that the build order should be :

- tooling/compiler
- packages/shared1
- packages/shared2
- apps/app1
- apps/app2

Although dependencies are declared in every package.json files properly (either as devDependency or dependency), runnin `pnpm -r run build` seems to build projects randomly. The result is that it doesn't compile (complaining it miss some dependent packages).

I thought pnpm is supposed to deal with build order. Is there anything I miss ?

Should I move to more complex tools like turborepo or rush?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, finally, that pnpm is not able, alone, to have such control.

I solved my issue by addin new tool on top of my repo.

I first gave a chance to [turbo](https://turborepo.org/) then [nxdev](https://nx.dev). Both are able to detect the dependency graph and build in the correct order

Comment: run `npx nx run-many --target=build` to build all packags in a workspace, see [package-based-repo-tutorial](https://nx.dev/getting-started/package-based-repo-tutorial#running-multiple-tasks) or [integrated-repo-tutorial](https://nx.dev/getting-started/integrated-repo-tutorial#running-multiple-tasks). nx is written in javascript, turbo is written in go (and rust). see also [nx: Explore the Graph](https://nx.dev/core-features/explore-graph) and [nx: Cache Task Results](https://nx.dev/core-features/cache-task-results)

Answer (score 1):

That's only half of the truth  - yes, you can !

You can utilize pnpm to resolve the build order of your workspace using `pnpm list` (https://pnpm.io/cli/list)

`pnpm list --parseable --recursive --only-projects` will list the dependency of your workspace projects in the order of their dependency for consumption in shell scripts

`pnpm list --json --recursive --only-projects` will list the dependency of your workspace projects in the order of their dependency and outputs the result as json tree structure.

You can even add pnpm option `--filter` to limit the introspected package by package name.